# How can I write a regular expression that is only activated if the string contains certain characters and numbers?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to develop some problems that my instructor gave me, and one of those problems is asking me to check if the input string complies with the following rules:

1. That the string contains numbers from 2 to 9.
2. That the string contains the letters TJQKA.
3. If within the string there is any other letter outside the mentioned ones, then the String is invalid.

EX:

643TJAKQ = Ok

72MAJTQ = Not Okay

1246AKJQ = Not Okay

AKT432 = Ok

This obviously is a Regex problem, because if I try to filter by lists, arrays or something else, It's going to take too much time just validating this (And I writting the code). I tried with this reg exp (`/[2-9]|(T|J|Q|K|A)/g`) but is garbage.

Comment: `\b[2-9TJQKA]+\b`

Comment: "*I tried with this reg exp (/[2-9]|(T|J|Q|K|A)/g) but is garbage*" What? Why is it garbage? What do you mean by this? Please elaborate.

Comment: @esqew It's too obvious, is not working. When I use this exp with the function "matches" in java, is always trowing false.

Comment: That said, check out this question: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Its "answer" has links to many other helpful pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following regex works: `^[2-9TJQKA]+$`

explanation:

`^`: start

`[2-9TJQKA]`:  define allowed values

`+`: allow more than one character Strings

`$`: end

Comment: Thank you very very very much for your explanations. I'm going to create a few custom ones to pratice and try.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define the allowed characters:

`[2-9TJQKA]+`

Answer (score 1):

```
Boolean okayOrNot = someString.matches("[2-9TJQKA]+");
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the regex: `\b[2-9TJQKA]+\b`

`2-9`-accept only numbers between 2 and 9

`TJQKA`-accept only these characters

`\b`-only words with only these characters

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bjyz8J/1) also on [free formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

Comment: The above code doesnt work for the following String: TJQK2345A

Comment: I think OP wanted java regex

Comment: it definitely seems like it should work, but when I run it, it doesn't match